# How to setup the correct transportation tableu for this Caterer Problem?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, linear-programming, dynamic-programming, algorithmic-game-theory

The problem said:

> A caterer must supply 110 napkins on Monday, 90 on Tuesday, 130 on
>   Wednesday, and 170 on Thursday. The caterer initially has no napkins
>   on hand. New napkins can be bought for 7 cents each. Used napkins can
>   be laundered for use the next day at 4 cents/napkin or laundered for
>   use in 2 days or more at 2 cents/napkin. At the end of the week, all
>   used napkins have no value. How can the caterer meet these demands at
>   minimal cost? (Hint> consider this as a transportation problem with
>   four sources-the new-napkin outlet and the first 3 days' collections
>   of used napkins.)

I try to setup the tableu but I can't apply the algoritm to find the correct distribution due, I can not be able to figure out the correct supply and demand in each extrem of the tableau.

Below, is the my tableu so far:

[image]

7 -cost of new napking
4- fast laundry
2- slow laundry

The minimal cost (show in book said): $22.4

I really apreciate any help, in set up this tablaeu.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to fill in the tableau from a graphical representation of the problem:

[image: Network representation of the caterer problem]

The difficulty comes from the fact that arcs are in both directions, meaning that destination nodes are also origin nodes, and vice versa. I think the following tableau might be correct, but not 100% sure:

[image]